# Get values from last 3 non-blank cells in a row

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I currently have an excel worksheet similar to the following (*#'s represent blank cells*)

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
37  21  30  32  25  22  34
#   17  26  28  27  17  31
#   #   #   #   #   #   38
25  23  27  35  33  #   #
27  11  23  #   #   #   #
```

In column 8 I need the sum of the last 3 non-blank cells (the number of columns is increased regularly).

An example of what I need to achieve is below:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7       8
37  21  30  32  25  22  34      25+22+34=81
#   17  26  28  27  17  31      27+17+31=75
#   #   #   #   #   #   38      N/A
25  23  27  35  33  #   #       27+35+33=95
27  11  23  #   #   #   #       27+11+23=61
```

I have managed to get very close with the `LARGE` function but obviously this only give me the 3 largest, not the last 3 non-blank:

```
=(LARGE(C3:J3,1)+LARGE(C3:J3,2)+LARGE(C3:J3,3))
```

Comment: Do u want VBA or NON VBA Solution?

Comment: VBA it is definitely possible by looping down column 8 - then inside the loop you would need to move from left to right looking for the first three non-blanks and each time either building a formula for column 8 or calculating the total. I'll not write this as I suspect somebody else will use worksheet functions which is the simpler route if available

Comment: I would prefer non-VBA if possible for ease of management, but VBA would be fine if there are no worksheet functions available.

Comment: There is a formula. Plz give me few moments. i am experimenting with it.

Comment: I am stuck with a scenario if there are say 2 34's in row 1 then what. I have managed the rest. Still experimenting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another one:

```
=IF(COUNT(A2:G2)<3,"NA",SUM(G2:INDEX(A2:G2,LARGE(COLUMN(A2:G2)*(A2:G2<>""),3))))
```

From http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/03/sum-last-three-golf-scores/

It identifies the column to sum from and since blank cells are zero, it doesn't matter how many are intermingled.

Comment: Oh yeah, Ctrl+Shift+Enter may be important :)  Thanks Barry

Answer (score 3):

If data is in A1:G1 try this formula in H1

`=IF(COUNT(A1:G1)>2,SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(9.99E+307,A1:G1)-1,1,-3)),NA())`

Comment: + 1 Well, I'll be damned! LOL. I also had a formula ready but the rpoblem was that it didn't work if there were two same numbers...

Comment: This seems to work in most cases, however with the following in A1:G1 I get 58 rather than 88 (30 # 25 # 33 # #) - again, # is blank

Comment: I assumed from your examples that there wouldn't be blanks in amongst the the numbers, try Dick's version....

Comment: Sorry barry, I hadn't noticed my example all contained numbers in blocks. Thank you very much for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

I know the pros here will hate this one. But I work with data in the hundreds of thousands of rows and millions of cells, And I prefer helper rows, and complex formulas over Array formulas any day. As it will cut calculations to fractions. Even if maintenance is more work, I spend less time fixing a formula once then waiting on calculations of arrays on every change of data (for me my data changes every 10 minutes) So, hundreds of thousands of arrays on millions of cells every 10 minutes will simply not work. So, here is just an alternative.

```
=IF(COUNT(A2:G2)<3,"NA",IF(COUNT(E2:G2)=3,SUM(E2:G2),IF(COUNT(D2:G2)=3,SUM(D2:G2),
 IF(COUNT(C2:G2)=3,SUM(C2:G2),IF(COUNT(B2:G2),SUM(B2:G2),IF(COUNT(A2:G2)=3,
 SUM(A2:G2)))))))
```

If there's not 3 values to sum it will return NA, other wise working right to left will check for the first cell with from that cell to the end has 3 number in it then will sum that.

If you data does involve more columns then your question. You can use dynamic ranges to clean up the code a little.

Another working non-array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNT(A2:G2)=3,A2:G2,IF(COUNT(B2:G2)=3,B2:G2,IF(COUNT(C2:G2)=3,C2:G2,
IF(COUNT(D2:G2)=3,D2:G2,IF(COUNT(E2:G2)=3,E2:G2,"NA"))))))
```

simply put will sum what ever range from the end has a count of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Newbee alert: I know the post is old however if anyones still out there, I'm keen to get help on derivative of the formula Dick provided whereby I'd like to run the count over several rows for example
 **[2 in this case]:**

=`IF(COUNT(A1:G2)<3,"NA",SUM(G2:INDEX(A1:G2,LARGE(COLUMN(A1:G2)*(A1:G2<>""),3))))`

Ultimately I'm trying to pull a sum of the last three cells with figures in running 12 accross

```
[A:L=months of year] by several rows down [1:5=consecutive years].
```

If anyone can shed light I'd be much obliged.

Many thanks: Ryan